# How to fetch a particular value from JSON if it exist

Tags: json, angular

I have a json and want to fetch some values if it exists or not null.
From below JSON, I want to extract "options" of "questionGroup". Challenge is at some places "questionGroup" is empty.

```
"surveyQuestions": [
    {
      "questionTitle": "Enter your name",
      "questionType": "Text",
      "questionGroup": {}
    },
    {
      "questionTitle": "Enter your age",
      "questionType": "Number",
      "questionGroup": {}
    },
    {
      "questionTitle": "Select your gender",
      "questionType": "Single choice",
      "questionGroup": {
        "options": [
          {
            "optionText": "Male"
          },
          {
            "optionText": "Female"
          }
        ],
        "showRemarksBox": false
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check whether the options are undefined or not.

```
// Iterate over survey questions
this.surveyQuestions.forEach( question => {
    // Check if present or not
    if(question.questionGroup.options!=undefined){
        console.log(question.questionGroup.options);
        return question.questionGroup.options;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for this.

```
let data = {"surveyQuestions": [
    {
      "questionTitle": "Enter your name",
      "questionType": "Text",
      "questionGroup": {}
    },
    {
      "questionTitle": "Enter your age",
      "questionType": "Number",
      "questionGroup": {}
    },
    {
      "questionTitle": "Select your gender",
      "questionType": "Single choice",
      "questionGroup": {
        "options": [
          {
            "optionText": "Male"
          },
          {
            "optionText": "Female"
          }
        ],
        "showRemarksBox": false
      }
    }
  ]}

let result = Array.from(data.surveyQuestions.filter(o => o.questionGroup.options), ({questionGroup}) => questionGroup.options);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
surveyQuestions.filter(s => s.questionGroup && Object.keys(s.questionGroup).length)
```